# How to get the first value from dynamic values

Tags: javascript

I want to store the first value from variable which always change. My idea use array to store it.
Are there others methods to achieve it?

```
let arr = [];
function test() {
    let r;
    r = Math.random() * 100;        //emulate to get the value dynamically
    arr.push(r);
    return r;
}

alert(test());
alert(test());
alert(arr[0]);      //Always get the first value
```

Comment: Well, you could set a variable to null and check if it's null then enter the value there, if it's not then don't. That way it always holds only the first one. Kind of like using a singleton.

Comment: `let firstValue = null;
function test(){
    let r = Math.random() * 100;
    if(firstValue === null){firstValue = r}
    return r;
}`

Answer (score 3):

Here the variable 'res' is assigned to null initially and checked inside the function for null, if res === null you can store the first occurrence to it. for the please be aware of 'let' and 'var' scopes

```js
var res = null;
function test() {
    let r;
    r = Math.random() * 100;        //emulate to get the value dynamically
    if(res === null) {
      res = r;
    }
    
    return r;
}

alert(test());
alert(test());
alert(res);
```

Comment: Math.random() * 100; Can return 0.

Comment: yeah perfect., i will adjust the code now, thank you so much! Just got clear it excludes '1' but includes '0' from the range :)